# Function fitting where one of the fitting parameter should be chosen from the list of fixed values

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimization

Let us assume that we have a closed form analytical function `y = a * x + b`. We have also experimental data to which this function should be fitted. Thus, error minimization by fitting right `a` and `b`, might be done. Attached `Python 3.8` code do this easily.

```
import time

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class Model:
    
    def __init__(self, x_exp, y_exp, params_init):
        
        self.x_exp = x_exp
        self.y_exp = y_exp
        self.params_init = params_init
        
        self.possible_b = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.method = "brute"
        self.tolerance = 1 * 10**(-10)
        
        self.res = None
        
    def _fun_linear(self, x, a, b):
        
        y = a * x + b
        
        return y

    def _model(self, params):
        
        a = params[0]
        b = params[1]
        
        y_fit = self._fun_linear(self.x_exp, a, b)
        
        err = np.linalg.norm(y_fit - self.y_exp)
        
        return err
    
    def fit(self):
        
        time_beg = time.time()
        self.res = minimize(fun=self._model,
                            x0=self.params_init)
        
        time_end = time.time()
        
        print(time_end - time_beg)
        print(self.res.x)
        print(self.res)

def f(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

x_exp = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y_exp = f(x_exp, a=1, b=2) + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 1000)

model = Model(x_exp, y_exp, [0, 0])
model.fit()
y_fit = f(x_exp, a=model.res.x[0], b=model.res.x[1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_exp, y_exp)
ax.plot(x_exp, y_fit)
fig.show()
```

Now, I would like do chose `b` value from my own list defined in the `self.possible_b` instead to approximate it by the used minimization method. Its some-kind of fixed values constrain to `b`.

Is it possible? How such kind of algorithms are called if they exist? Any libraries are able to do this?

Comment: I think the simplest way would be to do a least-squares fitting for each value of `self.possible_b` and use the fit with the smallest error.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about similar solution. But I have doubts related with tolerance. If everything will be converged, then everything will be on the same level of being ok. Am I wrong?